# Aren't variables in Python loops block scoped?

Tags: python, loops, scope, language-lawyer

I'm coming from JavaScript where "const" and "let" are block-scoped. I just noticed when there's a variable in Python inside a for block, that variable can be accesed outside in the main code after the loop finishes running.

```
for a_value in values:
   myName = "Zoltan"

print(myName) # prints "Zoltan"
```

In JavaScript I need to do something like this:

```
let myName; // The variable needs to declared outside to be accesed later outside

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  myName = "Zoltan";

console.log(myName)
```

So, Python doesn't do block scoping. Did I notice correctly?

Comment: Succinctly ... Yes, you noticed correctly.